# Get 2 divs to stretch out to fill the width of the wrapping div at all times

Tags: html, css

I've searched for this and read about floats, but I don't understand why I can't make 2 divs float equally in a wrapping div.

```css
#wrap {
    border: 1px solid red;   
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    
}

#gr1 {
   border: 1px solid blue;
   float: left;
   
  
}

#gr2 {
   border: 1px solid blue;  
   float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">  
  <div id="gr1">Group 1
  </div>

  <div id="gr2">Group 2
  </div>
</div>
```

I think this should make it so Group 1 and Group 2 are always equally filling  the width of the wrapping div like in the image below.  I'd like it to always be like that no matter the size of the browser.  I've tried making gr1 and gr2 50% width, but gr 2 just drops down below gr1.  What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
#wrap {
    border: 1px solid red;   
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    
}

#gr1 {
   border: 1px solid blue;
   float: left;
   
  
}

#gr2 {
   border: 1px solid blue;  
   float: left;
}

#gr1, #gr2 {
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">  
  <div id="gr1">Group 1
  </div>

  <div id="gr2">Group 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm glad to help. :) U can learn more about this property and its values here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Answer (score 3):

By default, setting the size of an element doesn't include any borders or padding, which is why your 50% size isn't working - the borders add an extra 2 pixels to the size of each element.

Using the box-sizing property allows you to change this behaviour, so that sizes include the border and padding. E.g.:

```css
#wrap {
    border: 1px solid red;   
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    
}

#gr1 {
   width: 50%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border: 1px solid blue;
   float: left;
   
  
}

#gr2 {
   width: 50%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border: 1px solid blue;  
   float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">  
  <div id="gr1">Group 1
  </div>

  <div id="gr2">Group 2
  </div>
</div>
```